# Can i take tab bar and custom title-bar in same Activity

Tags: android, tabbar, custom-titlebar

I have Tab-bar and custom title-bar in same activity.In static mode am able to display tab-bar and custom title-bar in the same activity. But when i assign dynamic values to custom title-bar attributes it shows error as

AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
Please provide any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

final LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.header_bar, null);

        //if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
        //I'm using a custom TextView with a custom font in my layout xml so all I need to do is set title
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.header_bar_title)).setText(this.getTitle());
        //assign the view to the actionbar
        this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

and make sure you do this before `setContentView()` method.